# Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function

Tags: javascript, magento, typeerror

I am trying to figure out a JS error I am receiving in a Magento e-commerce extension that I paid good money for, but support has been lacking on their end to fix this.  Error causes a spinning wheel of doom on page load that never goes away.

The following is the error I receive in the developer console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function
at findFirst (select.js:67)
at UiClass.normalizeData (select.js:193)
at UiClass.normalizeData (wrapper.js:109)
at UiClass.getInitialValue (abstract.js:200)
at UiClass.setInitialValue (abstract.js:143)
at UiClass._super (wrapper.js:106)
at UiClass.setInitialValue (select.js:302)
at UiClass.setInitialValue (wrapper.js:109)
at UiClass.initialize (abstract.js:70)
at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
```

This is the code section at line 67 of select.js **data.some(function (node) {** the error is referencing:

```
/**
 * Recursively loops over data to find non-undefined, non-array value
 *
 * @param  {Array} data
 * @return {*} - first non-undefined value in array
 */
function findFirst(data) {
    var value;

    data.some(function (node) {
        value = node.value;

        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            value = findFirst(value);
        }

        return !_.isUndefined(value);
    });

    return value;
}
```

I am hoping this is just some kind of typo error that I might be able to fix on my own?

Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. I am a coding novice.

Comment: `some` is a method of array objects. Either `data` is not an array or you have overwritten the original `some` method.

Comment: Almost certainly not a typo.  This will happen when the `findFirst` function is passed a value that does not have a `some` method.  Presumably it's expecting an array.

Comment: Check the code where you are calling the function findFirst and make sure you are passing the parameter data value is array.

Comment: The only two other instances of 'findFirst' in the script are the following:

Comment: /**
         * Matches specfied value with existing options
         * or, if value is not specified, returns value of the first option.
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
        normalizeData: function () {
            var value = this._super(),
                option;

            if (value !== '') {
                option = this.getOption(value);

                return option && option.value;
            }

            if (!this.caption()) {
                return findFirst(this.options);
            }
        },

Comment: /**
         * Select first available option
         *
         * @returns {Object} Chainable.
         */
        clear: function () {
            var value = this.caption() ? '' : findFirst(this.options);

            this.value(value);

            return this;
        },

Comment: Have you found it's solution?

Answer (score 4):

I've got this issue while creating a form using UI Components, specifically Select component. I was missing the **`caption`** element, so if anybody encounter this issue they might be missing an element.

```
<form>
...
<fieldset>
    ...
    <field name="select_example" formElement="select">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Select Example</label>
            <dataScope>select_example</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options>
                        <option name="1" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option #1</item>
                        </option>
                        <option name="2" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option #2</item>
                        </option>
                        <option name="3" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Option #3</item>
                        </option>
                    </options>
                    <caption translate="true">-- Please Select --</caption>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Comment: If a default isn't specified or a caption I got this error too.
If you don't want a caption but want a default value do:
```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                 </item>
             </argument>
```
This seems to allow you to remove the "caption" element

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2.1.8 there was a method removed that may affect certain extensions - it affected ours called getOptionArray().

To fix it in our extension in: Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/FixedSelectionType.php

```
'options' => FixedType::getOptionArray(),
```

becomes:

```
'options' => FixedType::getOptionsArray(),
```

and in the model/attribute folder add this method, in our case the full path is: Model/Attribute/Sources/FixedType.php

and above the public function getalloptions() method add this:

```
public static function getOptionsArray()
 {
     $result = [];

     foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
         $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
     }

     return $result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue in Magento 2.2.3 version too. The issue was found with the file, `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js`. 
We need to override and add the changes to the file as below. Find the code,

```
data.some(function (node) {
    value = node.value;

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value = findFirst(value);
    }

    return !_.isUndefined(value);
});
```

Replace with the updated code,

```
data = _.some(data, function (node) {
    value = node.value;
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value = findFirst(value);
    }

    return !_.isUndefined(value);
});
```

This solved the issue for me. Thanks!